# SQL Server doesn't accept server name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication, transactional-replication

Today we tried to create a transactional replication on our SQL Server 2008, but when we are trying to `Configure Distiribution` or `New Publication` we couldn't do so, and an error message as shown below occurred. But also I was connected database with no server name.

[image]

Then when I try again to connect as error message server name `WIN-7SRKNSIF0BK` and this time I get error as below. I was thinking maybe cause of my windows authentication but I tried to connect with `sa` user but again same problem.

Now I realize my SQL Server version is shown as "PreRelease", can this be the reason for the issues?

Because I have no problem for example 2012 2016 and other 2008, and none of them is not "PreRelease".

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 10.0.1600.22    
((SQL_PreRelease).080709-1414)
```

[image]

Comment: https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/ - yoour server is ancient. Why even bother ad not at some point go to something that is vagueley supported? I mean, seriously? 2008 prerelease?

Comment: 2008 PreRelease Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      10.0.1600.22 ((SQL_PreRelease).080709-1414 )
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools      2007.0100.1600.022 ((SQL_PreRelease).080709-1414 )
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      6.0.6002.18005 (lh_sp2rtm.090410-1830)
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.0.8112.16421
Microsoft .NET Framework      2.0.50727.8762
Operating System      6.0.6002

Comment: Actually i dont know before me someone who has worked in my company they created prerelease version. I think prerelease version is not supported  or any bug ?

Comment: Even RELEASE versions are not supported anymore an full of bugs. Which is why there are monthly updates issued. Not sure anyone will answer here, but if you can not bother to fix up your installation to something even remotely resembling current software first, I am not even bothering with a real analysis. You should have looong moved forward to something that is not so totally out of even licensing.

Comment: Thanks TomTom maybe i need to think about of migration. Cause everything looks normal but i cannot. Its definitely strange situation.

Comment: TomTom hi again, i realize something for example on my other servers server name and computer name is same. But on this server there are different. It can be a reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instance name should be the same as your computer name.

```
EXEC sp_dropserver @@Servername;
GO
EXEC sp_addserver 'WIN-7SRKNSIF0BK', 'local';
GO
```

Comment: thnaks for all drop add server fixed my trouble but after that my database mail has begin to cant send mail. Only when i give to relay everything begun works fine.

Comment: oh oh, sorry for that.
SQL server depend on instance name in different features.
i always think twice before changing my server name after installing my SQL server.